# Group / pack every N rows using "pack_rows" in Kable

Tags: r, tidyverse, kable, kableextra

I'm trying to use a vector in combination with "pack_rows" in kable (or "group_rows" - whichever works), to consistently 'group' a pre-defined number of rows.

I have a character vector called "stimuli_list", ordered alphabetically, containing the names of many individual items (e.g. "anchor", "apple", "ashtray") - too many to define one by one. For each of these individual items, I have 6 rows of corresponding data in a separate df (also arranged alphabetically). I want to group, or pack, all 6 rows of data under the single item label they correspond to. My desired output would look like:

```
            col1    col2      col3
anchor
            row 1   of data   for anchor
            row 2   of data   for anchor
            row 3   of data   for anchor
            row 4   of data   for anchor
            row 5   of data   for anchor
            row 6   of data   for anchor
apple
            row 1   of data   for apple
            row 2   of data   for apple
            row 3   of data   for apple
            row 4   of data   for apple
            row 5   of data   for apple
            row 6   of data   for apple
and so on...
```

But as I don't know how to define the number of rows to group, I'm getting this:

```
            col1    col2      col3
anchor
            row 1   of data   for anchor
apple
            row 2   of data   for anchor
ashtray
            row 3   of data   for anchor
balloon
            row 4   of data   for anchor
banana
            row 5   of data   for anchor
barrel
            row 6   of data   for anchor
basket
            row 1   of data   for apple
bear
            row 2   of data   for apple
and so on...
```

As the data is all ordered correctly, I simply need to tell pack_rows to do its job on every 6th row, rather than every single row. The code I currently have:

```
    b %>%
      kable("latex", longtable = T, booktabs = T, linesep = c("", "", "", "", "", "\\addlinespace")) %>%
      kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped","condensed")) %>%
      kable_styling(latex_options = c("repeat_header"), font_size = 6) %>%
      add_header_above(c(" " = 1, "Familiarity" = 2, "Visual Complexity" = 2, 
                         "Colour Diagnosticity" = 2, "Mental Imagery Agreement" = 2)) %>%
      pack_rows(index = table(a))
```

Any help appreciated!

---

**reprex:**

stimuli_list:

```
a <- structure(list(stim = c("anchor", "apple", "ashtray", "balloon", 
"banana", "barrel", "basket", "bear", "bell", "belt")), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Main data:

```
b <- structure(list(Photograph = c("anchor1-photo-colour", "anchor1-photo-grey", 
"anchor2-photo-colour", "anchor2-photo-grey", "anchor3-photo-colour", 
"anchor3-photo-grey", "apple1-photo-colour", "apple1-photo-grey", 
"apple2-photo-colour", "apple2-photo-grey"), Fam_Mean = c(3.55, 
2.97, 3.3, 2.81, 3.52, 3.1, 4.79, 4.85, 4.95, 4.4), Fam_SD = c(1.32, 
1.52, 1.56, 1.57, 1.33, 1.52, 0.49, 0.49, 0.22, 0.88), VisCom_Mean = c(2.95, 
2.81, 3.45, 3, 2.4, 2.35, 3.1, 2.19, 3, 2.4), VisCom_SD = c(1.12, 
0.93, 1.23, 0.97, 0.88, 1.09, 1.14, 1.08, 0.97, 0.99), ColDia_Mean = c(2.81, 
NaN, 3.5, NaN, 2.7, NaN, 3.43, NaN, 3.5, NaN), ColDia_SD = c(1.21, 
NA, 1.19, NA, 1.3, NA, 1.08, NA, 1.32, NA), MenIma_Mean = c(4.05, 
3.95, 3.75, 3.52, 3.8, 4.25, 4.15, 3.05, 3.76, 2.75), MenIma_SD = c(1.05, 
0.89, 1.25, 1.33, 1.01, 0.79, 0.88, 1.23, 1.04, 1.45)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `a` represents 10 different `stim`s, yet your `b` only seems to look at 2 of them (`anchor` and `apple`). Further, `table(a)` is only going to return lots of `1`s, so `kable` is only going to group one row at a time.

The mechanism we need it to be able to identify somehow the `anchor` in `anchor1-photo-colour` to extract that. If there is a means to do this without regexes earlier in your generation of `b`, then it might be better to do it there, since regexes can introduce problems if done incorrectly.

If we assume that all `anchor[0-9].*` photographs are concurrent (and same for other `stim`s), then we can do something like this:

```r
table(gsub("[0-9].*", "", b$Photograph))
# anchor  apple 
#      6      4
```

which is something we can pass to `pack_rows`.

I'll demonstrate using an html engine just for simplicity, it should be the same with your `"latex"` output.

```r
b %>%
  kable("html", longtable = T, booktabs = T, linesep = c("", "", "", "", "", "\\addlinespace")) %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped","condensed")) %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("repeat_header"), font_size = 6) %>%
  add_header_above(c(" " = 1, "Familiarity" = 2, "Visual Complexity" = 2, 
                     "Colour Diagnosticity" = 2, "Mental Imagery Agreement" = 2)) %>%
  pack_rows(index = table(gsub("[0-9].*", "", b$Photograph)))
```

[image: sample kable packed rows]

Comment: This worked perfectly! Many thanks. And sorry for the poor reprex, I just grabbed the first 10 rows from each var without noticing the mismatch.